# Well pipe leaking at where pipe comes to the house

Tags: plumbing, waterproofing, water-pressure, well

so here's my problem here:

[Well pipe leaking - images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJWiy.jpg)
[Well pipe leaking - video](https://vid.me/xVPK)

[image]
[image]
[image]

^ This was recorded march 28-th (so during spring thaw). Since it wasn't dripping since the spring - my assessment is the leakage was not from the well-pipe itself but rather by hydrostatic pressure caused by high water table resulting from the thaw perhaps?

Anyway - you can see previous owners hack repair attempts with multiple layers of what seems to be a roofing cement, insulation spray foam and what looks like a silicone caulking.

Questions:

a) How do I fix it for good? I don't mind excavating and redoing the whole thing.
b) Are there any well-pipe casings you can recommend?
c) If I drill a new hole through concrete - how do I waterproof that?

Comment: You'll at least have to remove that blobular mess; there's no way adding to that could end up being waterproof.

Comment: @DanielGriscom right - I'm going to drill a hole in different place and relocate pipe. But how do I waterproof that new hole? is it supposed to be sleeved?